# Background Color of Select Elements Not Changing with Site's Scheme in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, drop-down-menu, background-color

I have developed a Chrome extension that includes a button and a select element for a website that supports both light and dark modes. The button's color changes successfully according to the site's color scheme, but I'm facing an issue with the select element. While the color of the select element changes as expected, its background color remains unchanged, not adapting to the site's color scheme.

My goal is to make the background color of the select element change dynamically based on the site's color scheme. Note that the site's color scheme changes using the **`<html style="color-scheme: light;">`** declaration.

I attempted to set the background color of the select element to transparent, but this solution did not yield the desired result. Additionally, I tried adding a listener for the scheme changes in the **`content.js`** file, but it's not working.

Could anyone suggest a solution or workaround to achieve this dynamic background color change for the select element in my Chrome extension, considering the site's color scheme changes by **`<html style="color-scheme: light;">`**? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The listener for scheme change is the correct solution, but you also need to call the listener so it process the current theme.

Comment: It didn't work so can you give me a link of how to make it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a chrome extension that changes the theme of the site that I was using with a one-button click, so I searched in the code of the extension and then found this:

```
   var rootElement = document.documentElement;
    var classList = rootElement.classList;

    if (classList.contains('light')) {
    console.log('light.');
    } else {
    console.log('dark.');
    }
```

Though it's not the best, it serves my purposes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).